# H-Bridge simple performance

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

I design a simple H bridge. The bridge is controlled by a PWM signal with a frequency of 125kHz. 
The load is the LC resonance circuit. The maximum current is about 3A. 
Everything is powered by a Li-poly 14.4V battery. 
Dead-time is implemented by the control processor.
Are pull-up (R18, R28) and pull-down (R16, R26) resistors on the gate necessary?
Can I remove the resistors between the driver and the gate (R15, R17)?
Please verify the correctness, potential threats and suggestions.

[image]
[TC4428 Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001422G.pdf)
[AOD603A Datasheet](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOD603A.pdf)

regards

Comment: You need to ask a valid question for this site and provide enough supplementary information to support that question being answered. At the moment, no cigar.

Answer (score 0):

Without the pullup/pulldown resistors even the tiniest transient condition on startup may cause shoot-through and fry the bridge. I would not omit those.

Looking at the datasheet of the TC4428ACOA, I think you may be able to remove the gate drive series resistors. I don't see any limit on the drive that will be exceeded if you do. However they may be there to damp ringing, so you should check that with a scope if you're going to take them out.